# Snowflake Linux ODBC Driver

Tags: odbc, redhat, rhel, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does anyone know if the latest Snowflake ODBC driver for Linux (v2.19.16) is compatible with RHEL 6.8?

Comment: Why not try to install it and see?

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake customers have had success using the Snowflake ODBC driver on RHEL.  I would say the best thing to do is to test. As per the documentation, what is currently officially supported is CentOS 6 or higher.  CentOS is very close to being RHEL without the branding and support. In particular, the library versions are the same, so binaries that work on one will work on the other.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/odbc.html#odbc-driver